# Segmentation fault in list<Object*> iterator

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator, segmentation-fault

I'm learning C++, and now I have problems with iterators. This is my case: I have this code here.

```
// std::list<Dragon*> dragons = cave.getDragons();
for (std::list<Dragon*>::iterator it = cave.getDragons().begin(); it != cave.getDragons().end(); it++){
        os << std::endl << (*it)->getName();
}
```

It returns a Segmentation fault. This is my list and my getDragons() method:

```
std::list<Dragon*> dragons;
std::list<Dragon*> getDragons() const {return dragons;}
```

And my question is... Why do I have a Segmentation fault doing that like this, but if I use dragons variable, which is commented, don't? Thanks!

Comment: You have a list of `Dragon*`s, then create an iterator to the beginning of it, then drop the list and let it be destroyed. Then you proceed to compare it to an iterator to a similar destroyed list. At any rate, use a range-based for loop (foreach loop: `for (auto* dragon : cave.getDragons())`)

Comment: `getDragons()` returns a copy. Maybe you want a reference?

Comment: There's a tester, and it has to work with this code:

`auto it = cave->getDragons().begin();`

It works with the first solution for me, but not for the tester

Comment: Well, maybe I have to say that it works once, and only once. I can read the first element in the list, but not the second one.

Answer (score 1):

`getDragons()` returns a `std::list` by value, so every time you call `getDragons()`, you get a *copy* of the `dragons` list.  Your `for` loop is thus comparing iterators from different temporary `std::list` objects, and will be trying to dereference invalid iterators.

You need to do something more like this instead:

```
std::list<Dragon*> dragons = cave.getDragons();
for (std::list<Dragon*>::iterator it = dragons.begin(); it != dragons.end(); it++){
    os << std::endl << (*it)->getName();
}
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later, use a `for-range` loop instead:

```
for (Dragon *dragon : cave.getDragons()) {
    os << std::endl << dragon->getName();
}
```

Otherwise, you need to change `getDragons()` to return the `std::list` by reference instead:

```
const std::list<Dragon*>& getDragons() const {return dragons;}
```

Then your original `for` code would work, though it would still be calling `getDragons()` on every loop iteration.  It is best to cache the result of a single call to a local variable:

```
const std::list<Dragon*> &dragons = cave.getDragons();
for (std::list<Dragon*>::const_iterator it = dragons.begin(); it != dragons.end(); it++){
    os << std::endl << (*it)->getName();
}
```

Or, use the same C++11 `for-range` loop shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Your underlying error is, as Remy explained, the usage of copies of lists (which not only is error prone but also inefficient). Thus, the correct cure is to **never** create such copies (Remy's answer still proposes to do so). To this end, your `getDragons()` method should return a reference.

```
struct Cave
{
  /* ... */
  std::list<const Dragon*> const&getDragons() const;
};
```

Also, you should use the `auto` keyword whenever possible (and of course use at least the 2011 standard).

```
for(auto const&dragon : cave.getDragons())
  os << std::endl << dragon.getName();
```